# Get the same result of abi.encode function in Java

Tags: solidity, web3j, abi, java

let say we have the following function in solidity:

```
function tryAbiEncode (address  _address, uint8 _amount) public pure returns (bytes memory)
{
    return abi.encode("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n",_address, _amount);
}
```

If I executed the above function with the following parameters:

```
_address = 0xbfF89Fe7598f162ACC86CfC3267Eb132F69B7e2B
_amount = 10
```

I will get the below result:

```
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060000000000000000000000000bff89fe7598f162acc86cfc3267eb132f69b7e2b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001a19457468657265756d205369676e6564204d6573736167653a0a000000000000
```

My question is, how I can get the same results  but in Java using web3j library ? I mean how I can execute `abi.encode` but in Java ?

Thanks!

Comment: I dont think web3j has such a method. I found this method "web3Sha3(string)" which is equal to "keccak256(abi.encodePacked(string));"

Comment: here is also an artikel about abi.encode so you could try to implement it by yourself or find maybe someone who did :D https://medium.com/@libertylocked/what-are-abi-encoding-functions-in-solidity-0-4-24-c1a90b5ddce8

Comment: maybe this class and methods could help you https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/abi/src/main/java/org/web3j/abi/TypeEncoder.java

Answer (score 0):

`Web3j` does not provide such methods. However, you can tinker with the internal types to get what you're looking for.

A good place to start is the [ABI tests](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/abi/src/test/java/org/web3j/abi/DefaultFunctionEncoderTest.java).

You should define a [Function](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/038950fce418047982f4ab03abe267309f6eb2ef/abi/src/main/java/org/web3j/abi/datatypes/Function.java#L22) with the parameters you specified. Then, you can encode it the same way we are doing in most tests.

Answer (score 0):

*** TypeEncoder.encode([the generated type]) ***
If you are using a web3j client for the generation of the java code, your types will extend DynamicStruct which you you can use in TypeEncoder.encode to get the correctly encoded Type.

Lastly you need to append ethereum signed message and it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same result with web3j using `TypeEncoder` and `DynamicStruct`.

Note that the JavaScript control character `\x19` is represented as `\u0019` in Java, so that needs to be replaced accordingly.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.web3j.abi.TypeEncoder;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.DynamicStruct;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Uint;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Utf8String;

import java.math.BigInteger;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class AbiEncodingTest {

    @Test
    public void testAbiEncoding() {
        String result = "0x" +
                TypeEncoder.encode(new DynamicStruct(
                        new Utf8String("\u0019Ethereum Signed Message:\n"),
                        new Address("0xbfF89Fe7598f162ACC86CfC3267Eb132F69B7e2B"),
                        new Uint(BigInteger.valueOf(10))));
        assertEquals("0x" +
                "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060" +
                "000000000000000000000000bff89fe7598f162acc86cfc3267eb132f69b7e2b" +
                "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a" +
                "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001a" +
                "19457468657265756d205369676e6564204d6573736167653a0a000000000000", result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `FunctionEncoder` is what you look for?

```
@Test
public void testFunctionSimpleEncode() {
    Function function =
            new Function(
                    "baz",
                    Arrays.asList(new Uint32(BigInteger.valueOf(69)), new Bool(true)),
                    Collections.emptyList());
assertEquals(
        "0xcdcd77c0"
                + "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000045"
                + "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
        FunctionEncoder.encode(function));
}
```

[Web3j source code](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/abi/src/test/java/org/web3j/abi/DefaultFunctionEncoderTest.java)